How to change the appearance of the VS Code context menu in Windows/Ubuntu?
I have an issue with the VS Code context menu after a recent update. The context menu looks different from what I’m used to—it appears extremely ugly. Additionally, it only displays 5 items at a time despite having plenty of space, requiring me to scroll, which is quite annoying.
I'm using Ubuntu, and I suspect that this might be related to the issue. Is there any way to revert the context menu to its previous appearance?
I’ve tried changing some GNOME settings and searched through VS Code settings, but I haven't found anything that resolves the problem.
Version: 1.92.1
Commit: eaa41d57266683296de7d118f574d0c2652e1fc4
Date: 2024-08-07T20:16:39.455Z
Electron: 30.1.2
ElectronBuildId: 9870757
Chromium: 124.0.6367.243
Node.js: 20.14.0
V8: 12.4.254.20-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 6.5.0-44-generic

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy


Set "window.titleBarStyle": "custom", in settings.json. The setting's description reads:

Adjust the appearance of the window title bar to be native by the OS or custom. On Linux and Windows, this setting also affects the application and context menu appearances. Changes require a full restart to apply.


I'm on VSCode 1.92.2, Ubuntu 2024.04 LTS. Things seem to have changed slightly recently.
File->Preferences->Settings
Then search for "window.titleBarStyle". Flip this value from "native" to "custom".
This changes quite a few visual settings. (With the Light Modern theme the menu font became a bit too light to be clear on this machine. I couldn't be bothered finding a detailed setting to increase the font weight so have gone to Dark Modern.)
